# SQL statement inserting record twice

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert a row into a database while avoiding duplicates:

```
INSERT INTO signature_categories 
            (category) 
SELECT ( 'test' ) 
FROM   signature_categories 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT category 
                   FROM   signature_categories 
                   WHERE  category = 'test')
```

Why does it insert the record 'test' twice here?

Comment: Where/how are you running this query?

Comment: You likely have two signature_categories that do not have a category of type 'test'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have two rows in `signature_categories` and neither one has `'test'` in it.  The `NOT EXISTS` is evaluated over the pre-`INSERT`ed version of the table.

If you want to insert only one row, that depends on the database.

A typical method is:

```
INSERT INTO signature_categories (category) 
    SELECT x.category
    FROM  (SELECT 'test' as category) x 
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM signature_categories sc
                       WHERE sc.category = x.category
                      ) ;
```

A better approach is to let the update fail and have the database enforce data integrity:

```
ALTER TABLE signature_categories ADD CONSTRAINT unq_signature_categories_category
    UNIQUE (category);
```